# Use Faker to seed a different image for each card in online store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, faker, seed

A true newbie here ^^

I'm trying to use the Faker gem to seed x number of Items/Cards in an online store project. All good except for one thing. I don't know how to seed a different image per Item/Card created.

```rb
10.times do 
  Item.create!(title: Faker::Book.title, description: Faker::Lorem.sentence(5), price: prices.sample, image_url: Faker::LoremFlickr.image)
 end
```

Is there a way to seed a different image for each card?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [faker docs](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker#ensuring-unique-values) you can prefix your method call with `unique` like this:

```rb
10.times do 
  Item.create!(title: Faker::Book.title, description: Faker::Lorem.sentence(5), price: prices.sample, image_url: Faker::LoremFlickr.unique.image)
end
```

Comment: Thx Hackman, but by adding the .unique method creates only one card although the .create is in a loop. By removing it, 10 cards will be generated but with the same pic.

Comment: @BasilAlBader yeah after reading the docs again and try it myself, I found out that Faker only has 1 image to offer, so when you call unique on it, it will raise an exception. So back to your question: You can't get unique images from Faker.